# How to query a phrase with stopwords in ElasticSearch

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, elasticsearch

I am indexing some text with stopwords enabled and I would like to search against these using "match phrase" query without slop, but it looks like stopwords are still taking in account for terms positions.

Building index:

```
PUT /fr_articles
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "stop": {
               "type": "standard",
               "stopwords" : ["the"]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "test": {
         "properties": {
            "title": {
               "type": "string",
               "analyzer": "stop"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Add a document:

```
POST /fr_articles/test/1
{
    "title" : "Tom the king of Toulon!"
}
```

Search:

```
POST /fr_articles/_search
{
   "fields": [
      "title"
   ],
   "explain": true,
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "title": {
            "query": "tom king",
            "type" : "phrase"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Nothing found ;-(

Is there a way to fix it? Or maybe with multiple span queries, but I want the term near each other.

Thanks you,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The position increments cause this issue, yes.  While the stop word may be gone and not searchable, it still doesn't shove the two words up next to each other, so the query `"tom the king"` finds neither `"tom king"` nor `"such that tom will not be their king"`.

Often, when you remove something in analysis with a filter, it's not quite as if it was never there.  The intent of `StopFilter`, in particular, is to remove search hits resulting from uninteresting terms.  It is not to change the structure of the document or a sentence.

You used to be able to disable position increments, on `StopFilter`, but that option has been removed, as of Lucene 4.4.

---

Okay, forget that CharFilter tomfoolery.  Ugly hack, don't do that.

To query without using position increments, you need to configure that in your query parser, not in the analysis.  This can be done in elasticsearch, with a [Query String Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html), with `enable_position_increments` set to false.

Something like:

```
{
    "query_string" : {
        "default_field" : "title",
        "query" : "\"tom king\""
        "enable_position_increments" : false
    }
}
```

As a point of interest, similar solution in raw Lucene, by setting [`QueryParser.setEnablePositionIncrements`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParserBase.html#setEnablePositionIncrements(boolean)).

Comment: Thanks you, looks like is the only solution to prevent position incrementing.   To me it sounds like a bug from "https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/trunk/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/search/PhraseQuery.java" Lucene code source, phantom terms should not be taking in account for Phrase query since they are not here!

Comment: This file sorry: https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/trunk/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/search/ExactPhraseScorer.java

Comment: No, this is *most definitely* by design.  The point is to not muddy scoring with matches on "the", and other terms that aren't interesting.  It's even provided as an example of how to handle position increments correctly in the [analysis package summary](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_2_1/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/package-summary.html) (see the section titled "Token Position Increments").  Hang on a second...

Comment: Okay, updated with a much better solution.  Don't know for sure whether there is some way to make a `match_phrase` behave similarly.

Comment: This will disable increment for query only isn'it?

Comment: @femtoRgon this doesn't seem to be working on ES 2.3

Answer (score 0):

There was an option `enable_position_increments: false` that you could set e.g. in a stop filter, but it has been deprecated since Lucene 4.4

This is the related Lucene issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-4065

In other words, the best way to go at the moment is probably to use the slop option, until the Lucene issue is fixed

Comment: Hello thanks you, I know this deprecated option ;-(  slop will take in account any word whereas I want take in account only stopwords.